# Can every math problem be visualised?

Tags: soft-question, visualization

Basically, title.

Can **everything** in mathematics be represented graphically one way or another?

Comment: The answer is NO

Comment: It is already hard to visualize $\mathbb{R}^4$ (actually I am not able to, but I know people who say they can, and there are ''techniques'' that can help you), you can guess what's the answer whenever you consider far more abstract things.

Comment: @AlbertoDebernardi can you explain to me like I'm five what $r^4$ means? I do pre-calculus, but am curious because I see it everywhere on this site?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^4 $ is a four-dimensional space.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ denotes the set of real numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number). Then, $\mathbb{R}^n$ denotes "$n$ copies of $\mathbb{R}$", roughly speaking. The world you live in is represented by $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e., 3-dimensional space. So $\mathbb{R}^4$ would be the 4-dimensional space.

Comment: So in mathematics we can deal in 4D universes without having to think in 4D, and this is an example of how we cannot visualise something?

Comment: You know, putting letters onto a page ... that is a "graphical" representation.

Comment: Just a note: I voted to close because "This is not mathematics". In my view, "visualization" is a psychological phenomenon: Some type of diagram or other symbolism causes _an emotional sensation of comprehension_. One might equally argue that _nothing whatsoever can be visualized_, in that we never have direct access to the nature of a thing, only to a mental model. While this type of speculation and debate may be interesting (and relevant to mathematical work), it's "not mathematics" in the sense I understand for this site.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang A written proof causes likewise an "emotional sensation of comprehension" (that's what mathematics causes, basically). Visual proofs can be as clear and as sound as if they were written. See *proof without words* on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_without_words) or better on [Math Overflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I agree that much of the elementary school math can be visualised, however, it does not answer the question if **everything** in math can be visualised. Visualsing proofs, if possible, is good. Is it always possible?

Comment: @Nyfiken I think we should first agree on what "visualizing" means here. I like GEdgar's comment : words are also a graphical representation. Are they fundamentally different from a drawing/sketch/plot ? When I'm writing on a piece of paper to prove something mathematically, I use equally well words, formulas or drawings, and I don't see the point to make a distinction. Is there even a distinction ? Is a flow diagram "visual" ? More visual than a formula ? Everything that can be convincing is appropriate, no matter how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to visualize things as they go to higher dimensions . For example consider $\Bbb{R}P^n$(the real projective space). For, $n=1$ this is just the circle but as $n$ value increases it becomes very difficult to visualize it. So questions involving $\Bbb{R}P^n$ become very difficult to visualize.

For that matter consider the Poincare conjecture in higher dimensions . It is nearly impossible to visualize it because it goes to such higher dimensions.

**Edit:** Since you are not familiar with these spaces I will give you a more easier example. Consider $S^1$ this is your normal circle , $S^2$ your sphere, But for $S^3$ we have issues. Because you know that $S^1$ lies in $\Bbb{R}^2$, $S^2$ lies in $\Bbb{R}^3$ . But $S^3$?? This lies in $\Bbb{R}^4$. Since it is difficult to visualize $\Bbb{R}^4$ it is difficult to visualize $S^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Not true. If everything could be represented visually the science called geometry, not mathematics.

Comment: I don't get how something cannot be represented visually in any way? What is an example?

Comment: @silenceislife Visualise $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$. Or $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x^k=\frac{x^k-1}{x-1}$.

Comment: @Nyfiken Those both have geometric interpretations, which I would call "visualizing."

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Visualisation = reducing to 3D geometry. Visualise Banach-Tarski paradox.

Comment: The two things you referred to above could be reduced to 2D geometry. Banach-Tarski already is 3D.